# Error while using Command line interface

Tags: data-loader, commandline

While running encrypt.bat -e  "C:\temp\key.txt"

I am getting the error below :

> 014-09-10 15:31:06,811 INFO [main] security.EncryptionUtil main
>   (EncryptionUti l.java:289) - Invalid option format: ûe

Answer (score 2):

I guess you copy pasted command `encrypt.bat -e "C:\temp\key.txt"` from some website.

It should be minus sign instead of dash, Can you try to type it and run it. You may find some helping steps [here](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/tutorial-of-command-line-dataloader-salesforce/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change to encrypt -e "C:\temp\key.txt"

You may need to include the password and security token as you're not telling encrypt what to encrypt. e.g.
encrypt -e myPasswordmySecurityToken "c:\temp\key.txt"

Comment: Tried but getting same error

Comment: I tried : encrypt.bat -e <Password+Securitytoken>  "C:\temp\key.txt" , Im trying to create a encrypted password.                                                                                        https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=command_line_create_enc_password.htm&language=en_US

Comment: don't use .bat in the command; just encrypt and it'll work. e.g. encrypt -e myPassword "c:\temp\key.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Install Java 32 Bit and try again.

It might be possible that your machine is 64-bit operating system and you have installed Java JDK 64-bit but Data loader requires 32-bit java to run these commands. Java should be installed in this location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java".

Don't forget to change environment variable path also.